# How to pass a fill-box thru centre of nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, dot2tex, dot2texi

So I want to draw a component that ould look like in visual programming - with in's and out's. I want to keep it in a box. So I try to fit a box, yet its a bit off

Here is how it looks:
[image]

Here is minimal code sample (focus on last 3 lines):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,petri,positioning, fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle,
        thick,
        draw=blue!75,
        fill=blue!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    },
    transitionH/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum width=8mm,
        inner ysep=2pt
    },
    transitionV/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum height=8mm,
        inner xsep=2pt
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=0.8]


\begin{dot2tex}[dot,tikz,codeonly,styleonly,options=-s -tmath]
digraph MyGraph {
    rankdir=LR;

subgraph cluster_4386357488 {
    label = " <<GrowLamp>>"
    {rank=source;
        in_1 [ label="", style="place" ]
        in_2 [ label="", style="place" ]
        in_3 [ label="", style="place" ]
    }
    {
        middle_1 [label="", style="transitionV"]
        middle_2 [label="", style="place"]
    }
    {rank=sink;
        out_1 [label="", style="transitionV"]
        out_2 [label="", style="transitionV"]
    }
    in_1 -> middle_1;
    in_2 -> middle_1;
    in_3 -> middle_1;

    middle_1->middle_2;

    middle_2->out_1;
     middle_2->out_2;

}
}
\end{dot2tex}
\node[draw,dotted,fit=(in_1.north)  (in_3.south) (out_1.north) (out_2.south)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A dotted box is slightly off. how to make it pass thru all in\out nodes centres?

Desired outcome in form of red box:
[image]

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC: fixed!)

Comment: I still have a compilation error.

Comment: Please try https://www.overleaf.com/read/pcbfqcjknkxz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this ?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,petri,positioning, fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle,
        thick,
        draw=blue!75,
        fill=blue!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    },
    transitionH/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum width=8mm,
        inner ysep=2pt
    },
    transitionV/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum height=8mm,
        inner xsep=2pt
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=0.8]


\begin{dot2tex}[dot,tikz,codeonly,styleonly,options=-s -tmath]
digraph MyGraph {
    rankdir=LR;

subgraph cluster_4386357488 {
    label = " <<GrowLamp>>"
    {rank=source;
        in_1 [ label="", style="place" ]
        in_2 [ label="", style="place" ]
        in_3 [ label="", style="place" ]
    }
    {
        middle_1 [label="", style="transitionV"]
        middle_2 [label="", style="place"]
    }
    {rank=sink;
        out_1 [label="", style="transitionV"]
        out_2 [label="", style="transitionV"]
    }
    in_1 -> middle_1;
    in_2 -> middle_1;
    in_3 -> middle_1;

    middle_1->middle_2;

    middle_2->out_1;
     middle_2->out_2;

}
}
\end{dot2tex}
%\node[draw,dotted,fit=(in_1.center)  (in_3.center) (middle_2.center)] {};
\draw[red,dotted,thick] ([yshift=2mm]in_1.north) --([yshift=-2mm]in_3.south)-| (out_1.center)|-cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nope, added desired loo to the Q

Comment: See my update now